# How to properly "declare" a module? (TS7016)

Tags: typescript

First, here's my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        "strict": true,
        "importHelpers": false,
        "inlineSources": true,
        "noEmitOnError": true,
        "pretty": true,
        "module": "commonjs",
        "noImplicitAny": true,
        "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": false,
        "removeComments": true,
        "preserveConstEnums": false,
        "sourceMap": true,
        "lib": ["es2017","esnext.asynciterable"],
        "skipLibCheck": true,
        "outDir": "dist",
        "target": "es2018",
        "declaration": true,
        "types" : ["node"],
        "resolveJsonModule": true,
        "esModuleInterop": false
    },
    "files": [
        "src/DatabaseWrapper"
    ],
    "exclude": [
        "node_modules"
    ]
}
```

Now I've tried to import a JavaScript library:

```
 import Napi from '@org/napi-js';
```

And I get this error:

> TS7016: Could not find a declaration file for module 'napi-js'. '/home/mpen/Projects/my-project/node_modules/@org/napi-js/dist/index.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.
>   Try `npm install @types/org__napi-js` if it exists or add a new declaration (.d.ts) file containing `declare module 'org__napi-js';

The `@types/org__napi-js` doesn't exist, so that's no good. So how do I properly declare it?

I've tried creating a file, `types/org__napi-js.d.ts'` with just this in it:

```
declare module 'org__napi-js';
```

And then I tried updating my `tsconfig.json` so it can find it:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "baseUrl": "./",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["types/*"]
        }
    },
    ...
```

But that didn't help any.

What am I supposed to do? Or, more explicitly:

1. How do I tell TypeScript where to find my module?
2. What's the minimum amount of code that needs to go in this module to just say the default export is `any`?

I think I want to put all these stubs in `types/`, and my source in `src/` unless  there's some standard way to organize a TS project.

Answer (score 21):

OK, so through a lot of trial and error, it turns out TypeScript is *lying* about wanting a module called `org__napi-js`, what it *really* wants is `@org/napi-js`.

And, if you're unfamiliar with how `paths` works as I was, TypeScript looks up the file as its needed based on the module name, so the paths *must match*, and that includes the `@org` directory.

So, I was on the right track by updating my `tsconfig.json`:

```
{
    "compilerOptions": {
        ...
        "baseUrl": ".",
        "paths": {
            "*": ["types/*"]
        }
    },
```

That says look in the `types` dir for modules.

Then create the module file, `types/@org/napi-js.d.ts`. All it needs is:

```
declare module '@org/napi-js';
```

Note how it *does* include the `@namespace/`.

That's it. Your project should compile now.

Comment: > it turns out TypeScript is _lying_ about wanting a module called `org__napi-js`

Want to [file an issue](https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/) or shall I?

Comment: @MattMcCutchen I was just typing one up actually, but then I found someone already created it: https://github.com/Microsoft/TypeScript/issues/23999 Thanks for offering though!

Comment: @mpen, which version of TS are you using?

Comment: @mpen, how did you come to the conclusion that you have to add `paths` to your `tsconfig.json` file? I was under the impression that you should use `typeRoots`

Comment: @hendrikswan I read somewhere that `typeRoots` was the old way of doing it and `paths` is the new hot thing. AFAICT, `typeRoots` means TS will try to load *everything* in those dirs, whereas `paths` is a little more specific, so I guess it's preferred?? Not sure. Just a noob here. Edit: `ts-node` [says](https://github.com/TypeStrong/ts-node#help-my-types-are-missing) to use `paths` for "module definitions" and `typeRoots` for global defs.

Comment: @hendrikswan I'm using TypeScript 3.0.1

Comment: @mpen, thanks for letting me know! I managed to get our setup working using your approach in the end!

Answer (score 19):

An alternative to creating an empty declaration is ts-ignore:

```
// @ts-ignore
import Napi from '@org/napi-js';
```

Answer (score 3):

I had a similar problem with @google-cloud/some-lib and couldn't get it to work the way explained above.

I ended up with a file in my src directory containing "declare module '@google-cloud/some-lib';" and no specific configuration, eg no paths or basePath configuration. The name of the file does not matter, as long as it ends .d.ts.

Tested with Typescript 3.0.3 and 2.4.2

Took me half day to fix. Thank you Typescript :)

Answer (score 3):

For libraries without @types/module-name file, I enabled this in my tsconfig.json:

```
"moduleResolution": "node"
```

It specifies how Typescript looks up a file from a given module specifier.

If that doesn't work either, you can try adding `// @ts-ignore` before the import like this:

```
// @ts-ignore
import Napi from '@org/napi-js'
```

Answer (score 0):

This error, TS7016, arrives if you try to import a JavaScript (not typescript) module with a relative specifier (‘./path/to/file.js’) and don’t have allowJs set to true in tsconfig. [For example](https://github.com/vitejs/vite/discussions/14159).