# Could not find a declaration file for module 'redux-saga/effects'. '.../redux-saga-effects-npm-proxy.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type. TS7016

Tags: node.js, reactjs, typescript, react-redux

```
<path-to-project>/client/src/sagas/index.ts
TypeScript error in <path-to-project>/client/src/sagas/index.ts(1,46):
Could not find a declaration file for module 'redux-saga/effects'.
'<path-to-project>/client/.yarn/cache/redux-saga-npm-1.1.3-f4b0ce38ee-4ea0bf0d4f.zip/node_modules
/redux-saga/dist/redux-saga-effects-npm-proxy.cjs.js' implicitly has an 'any' type.  TS7016

> 1 | import { put, takeEvery, select, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
    |                                              ^
```

I just can't figure out how to fix the type of this import statement.

The packages are listed below if needed.

```
yarn info --name-only | grep 'type\|redux'
├─ @types/base64-js@npm:1.3.0
├─ @types/jest@npm:27.0.2
├─ @types/node@npm:16.11.6
├─ @types/qrcode.react@npm:1.0.2
├─ @types/rc-tooltip@npm:3.7.5
├─ @types/react-copy-to-clipboard@npm:5.0.2
├─ @types/react-dom@npm:17.0.11
├─ @types/react-redux@npm:7.1.20
├─ @types/react-router-dom@npm:5.3.2
├─ @types/react-timeago@npm:4.1.3
├─ @types/react@npm:17.0.34
├─ @types/redux-saga@npm:0.10.5
├─ @types/uuid@npm:8.3.1
├─ react-redux@npm:7.2.6
├─ redux-saga@npm:1.1.3
├─ redux@npm:4.1.2
├─ typescript@patch:typescript@npm%3A3.9.10#~builtin<compat/typescript>::version=3.9.10&hash=ddd1e8
└─ typesocket@npm:1.0.1
```

EDIT: Okay, this is weird. For some god-forbidden reason, using nodeLinker with yarn fixes this issue. Even so, I'd appreciate if anybody can find a proper fix for this while still retaining PnP.

Comment: `@types/redux-saga` can solve it

Comment: @NishargShah Tried it and it didn't. Sorry.

Answer (score 0):

I've ran into the same issue after upgrading yarn to PNP.

As a workaround, you can set `"noImplicitAny": false,` in the `tsconfig.json` (mentioned [here](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/32148)).

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    …
    "noImplicitAny": false,
  }
}
```

It's not necessarily a proper solution, but it should at least make your build pass until there is a proper fix (in redux-saga, typescript or yarn).

I've also tried to disable the TS warning on the import line with `// @ts-ignore` (suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51638818/how-to-properly-declare-a-module-ts7016#57118563) to fix the TS7016), but that did not work and produced the same error:

```
// @ts-ignore
import { put, takeEvery, select, call } from 'redux-saga/effects';
```